# How to show All items as first index in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have one `UICollectionView` , in which I am fetching some category name and i am display that name and when user press any cell in `UICollectionView`, that particular data will show in down of different `UICollectionView` (second `UICollectionView`).

So what I need is, for example in my `UICollectionView` is look like this means :

```
"Gems gaster royel mems"
```

I need to show :

```
 "All items Gems gaster royel mems"
```

How to add dynamically `All items` in my first index of my collection view, so that if user press that collection view cell - All items-I need to show all product that available in my db.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
 let cell = collectionview1.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! smallDetail_cell

            cell.productName.text = BTdata2[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].BTNames2

            return cell

        }
```

Comment: add your collectionview cellForItemAtIndexPath in your question

Comment: Do you mean accordion?

Comment: @iOSAppDev  sorry i am new to ios. Not able to understand what is accordion ??

Comment: Google = "uicollectionview accordion"

Comment: @BhavinRamani if i add like this, then when i press that cell, does it will show all product available in my db. I have already done api calling and i am having all product data model. If i do like this , how can i write on click of that `All item` to show all product in my second colelction view

Comment: @mack your old project ?

Comment: @BhavinRamani may be, its also an another solution by adding button before to the collection view.But, i dont know how to add then action for that button to show the collection view data

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya yes dude

Comment: Just simply send me your new project i make changes in it @mack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var selectedindex : NSInteger = 0 

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

        if(collectionView == collectionview1)
        {
            return BTdata2.count + 1

        }
        else
        {
             return Productdata.count

        }

    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
     let cell = collectionview1.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! smallDetail_cell

            //cell.productName.text = BTdata2[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].BTNames2

        if selectedindex == indexPath.row{
            cell.productName.textColor = UIColor.red
        }else{
           cell.productName.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.productName.text = "All Items"
        }else{

            cell.productName.text =  BTdata2[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - 1].BTNames2!
        }
        return cell
 }



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
       if collectionView == collectionview1 {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                print("all item show here click")

            }else{
               print("your button click here like ",BTdata2[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - 1].BTNames2!)
                // write code for display all selected category item..
            }
           selectedindex = indexPath.row
           collectionview1.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

**Output** :

all item show here click

your button click here like  Smartphones

your button click here like  Laptops

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
        let cell = collectionview1.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! smallDetail_cell

        if indexPath.row == 0{
            cell.productName.text = "All items"
        }else{
            cell.productName.text = BTdata2[((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) - 1].BTNames2
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Update your `collectionView(_ numberOfItemsInSection:)` with following,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return BTdata2.count + 1
}
```

Comment: How can i do the did select method for the `All item` to show my all data in my collection view

Comment: You need to pass BTData2 object from `didSelect`, show me you you are passing data to next `ViewController` right now

Comment: Yes, but i have `All item` , then another collection view cell. How can i do that seperate did select for `All item` as well as other data label

Comment: Basically you need to give `IBOutlet` to both 'CollectionViews' and in `didSelect` check which view controller is there, then perform tasks accordingly.